# Problema con FontAwesome, no me reconoce ningun icono

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

estoy usando bootstrap pero llevo rato intentando añadir FontAwesome y no me deja estoy haciendo el  que me coloca en la pagina desde hace rato que es

```
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/solid.js" integrity="sha384-+Ga2s7YBbhOD6nie0DzrZpJes+b2K1xkpKxTFFcx59QmVPaSA8c7pycsNaFwUK6l" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/fontawesome.js" integrity="sha384-7ox8Q2yzO/uWircfojVuCQOZl+ZZBg2D2J5nkpLqzH1HY0C1dHlTKIbpRz/LG23c" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

en el header y al momento de colocar cualquier icono en el body , por ejemplo

```
<i class="fab fa-apple"></i>
```

y no me sale nada.

Lo he intentado en la pag que estoy haciendo y nada e intente desde un archivo prácticamente virgen y sigue sin hacer nada.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El problema es que no estás importando Font Awesome **brands**.

Desde la versión 5 se dividió en "brands", "solid" y "regular" para su versión gratuita

La solución es importar el script con los íconos de "brands" `https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/brands.js`, aparte de los íconos que desees utilizar, ya sean "regular" o "solid"

```html
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/brands.js" integrity="sha384-sCI3dTBIJuqT6AwL++zH7qL8ZdKaHpxU43dDt9SyOzimtQ9eyRhkG3B7KMl6AO19" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/fontawesome.js" integrity="sha384-7ox8Q2yzO/uWircfojVuCQOZl+ZZBg2D2J5nkpLqzH1HY0C1dHlTKIbpRz/LG23c" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<i class="fab fa-apple"></i>
```

Otra opción es importar todo Font Awesome `https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js`, que no lo recomiendo a menos que el uso de los íconos en tu aplicación lo justifique.

```html
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-SlE991lGASHoBfWbelyBPLsUlwY1GwNDJo3jSJO04KZ33K2bwfV9YBauFfnzvynJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<i class="fab fa-apple"></i>
```

Answer (score 1):

He probado y me ha funcionado así

Espero que te sirva :)

```
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-SlE991lGASHoBfWbelyBPLsUlwY1GwNDJo3jSJO04KZ33K2bwfV9YBauFfnzvynJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Enlaza esta url y por ejemplo usa esto así

```
 <h1><i class="fab fa-apple"></i>Hola soy una manzana</h1>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css" />
    <!-- <script src="main.js"></script> -->
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-SlE991lGASHoBfWbelyBPLsUlwY1GwNDJo3jSJO04KZ33K2bwfV9YBauFfnzvynJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1><i class="fab fa-apple"></i>Hola soy una manzana</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Otra respuesta: espero tambien te sirva.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.4/js/all.js"></script>
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.4/js/v4-shims.js"></script> 
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.4/js/fontawesome.js"> </script>

</head>
<body>
  <!-- "close" is an alias to "times", V5 is <i class="fa fa-times"></i> -->
  <i class="fa fa-close"></i>

  <!-- Renamed to "image", V5 is <i class="fa fa-image"></i> -->
  <i class="fa fa-picture"></i>

  <!-- Needs the "fab" prefix, V5 <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i> -->
  <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>

  <!-- "far" prefix, lose the "-o", V5 <i class="far fa-circle"></i> -->
  <i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>

    <i class="fab fa-apple"></i>   
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me ocurrió el mismo problema; creé mi free kit y en vez de íconos aparecían pequeños cuadrados.

Mi solución fue revisar la configuración y cambiar la versión a la más actual (la 6.x.), de este modo mis íconos free comenzaron a cargar correctamente.