# FontAwesome no me reconoce los iconos

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

Quiero agregar un icono de un ojo y el proyecto no me reconoce el link que FontAwesome me da.
Probe con los links que dejaron en preguntas similares (como [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/148183/problema-con-fontawesome-no-me-reconoce-ningun-icono)) pero nada.

Este es usando los links que dejaron en la pregunta:

```html
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/brands.js" integrity="sha384-sCI3dTBIJuqT6AwL++zH7qL8ZdKaHpxU43dDt9SyOzimtQ9eyRhkG3B7KMl6AO19" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/fontawesome.js" integrity="sha384-7ox8Q2yzO/uWircfojVuCQOZl+ZZBg2D2J5nkpLqzH1HY0C1dHlTKIbpRz/LG23c" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<i class="fab fa-eye"></i>
```

Y éste el link que me proporciona la web de FA:

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/f1e1a05e58.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<i class="fa-solid fa-eye"></i>
```

Probandolo acá veo que sí funciona, pero en mi proyecto no, en mi pagina web se ve como un cuadrado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo uso aca:

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/f1e1a05e58.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
<div class="mb-4 col-6 mx-auto">
   <label for="password" class="form-label col-lg-offset-2">Contraseña</label>
   <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required />
   <span id="ver"><i class="fa-solid fa-eye"></i></span>
</div>
```

Estas son las librerias que estoy utilizando (Las paso por las dudas, no deberian estar haciendo conflicto)

Comment: Prueba dejar el script fontawesome al final, es decir que se carguen primero las otras librerías.

Comment: fue lo primero que hice y no funciona

Comment: 1) En la consola del navegador da un error? 2) Inspecciona el icono, luego busca la pestaña "calculado" y verifica que font-family tiene

Comment: 1) La consola no tira ningun error, 2) El font-family que hay es 'Gotham' sans-serif

Comment: Ahi creo que era el error, el font-family

Comment: Ahí debería aparecer tachado fontawesome si es que ha sido pisado por otra regla css. Si no aparece, posiblemente es porque no se cargó el estilo, una de las causas es que estes usando http y estas llamando a un https o problemas de cors

Comment: Prueba pasando toda la etiqueta `<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/f1e1a05e58.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>` al final del documento, antes de cerrar la etiqueta `</body>`. Borrar la caché del navegador e intenta de nuevo.

Comment: Puedes ver la pestaña de red de las herramientas de desarrollo de Chrome a ver si encuentras algo que no esté cargando como debe. O quizá la pestaña de rendimiento te dé alguna pista.

Comment: En el snippet funciona. El problema ha de estar en otra parte.

Comment: No todos los iconos son gratuitos...